# Kubernates: How to get the external IP of the service or the DNS attached to it in route53

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-route53

I have used external DNS with my load balancer. Now I have to print the output on my Gitlab console.

This is the service:

```
test-dev-service-lb-http            LoadBalancer   192.20.18.123   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-623196XX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   443:32479/TCP
```

Now I can get the ELB endpoint on the console by running a command: `kubectl get svc -o wide`. But I want to print the DNS attached to this ELB in Route 53 as well.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes doesn't have the knowledge of DNS records pointing to your LB.
You should use [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html) to get Route 53 records.

Comment: Yeah. So I got the elb end point. what was the command to get the DNS of an ELB from route53? Thanks for helping